# Adding child to pixi.js sprite distorts childs dimensions & location

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I use typescript & pixi.js v4.8.2. Here is the code that helps me create all the containers.

```
    let appWidth = app.renderer.view.width
    let appHeight = app.renderer.view.height
    mapContainer = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources.water_pattern.texture);
    mapContainer.height = app.renderer.view.height
    mapContainer.width = appWidth - appWidth / 5 - appWidth / 14
    mapContainer.x = app.renderer.view.width / 14

    cardContainer = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
    cardContainer.tint = 0x3C2415;
    cardContainer.height = app.renderer.view.height / 2
    cardContainer.width = app.renderer.view.width / 14

    actionContainer = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
    actionContainer.tint = 0x00FF00;
    actionContainer.height = app.renderer.view.height / 2
    actionContainer.width = app.renderer.view.width / 14
    actionContainer.y = app.renderer.view.height / 2

    chatContainer = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
    chatContainer.tint = 0x008080;
    chatContainer.height = app.renderer.view.height / 2
    chatContainer.width = app.renderer.view.width / 5
    chatContainer.x = app.renderer.view.width * 4 / 5

    playerContainer = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
    playerContainer.tint = 0xCCCCCC;
    playerContainer.height = app.renderer.view.height / 2
    playerContainer.width = app.renderer.view.width / 5
    playerContainer.y = app.renderer.view.height / 2
    playerContainer.x = app.renderer.view.width * 4 / 5

    app.stage.addChild(mapContainer, cardContainer, actionContainer, chatContainer, playerContainer)
```

Then I try to create sprites in containers:

```
    let settlement = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources.settlement_red.texture)
    settlement.height = 10
    settlement.width = 10
    settlement.x = 0
    settlement.y = 0
    chatContainer.addChild(settlement)
```

and the result of my code is this:

[image]

The house is clearly not at x & y. And it is clearly not 10 to 10 pixels. Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Note that I know I can use [PIXI.Container](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html) but I will be adding background images. I find it to be better when the background image is a part of the container instead of being a separate object inside the container thus I'm using sprites.

Lastly my app code:

```
    app = new PIXI.Application({ // http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Application.html
            antialias: true,    // default: false
            forceCanvas: true, // default: false (forces canvas rendering instead of webgl rendering)
        }
    );
    app.renderer.autoResize = true;
    app.renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
    app.renderer.view.style.display = "block";
    app.renderer.autoResize = true;
    app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);
```

Comment: I need to understand your situation better: Why do you want to use the canvas renderer instead of webgl? forcing canvas is only good for older browser support and causes many issues in pixi (that I've faced). Secondly, could you verify that it is only settlement sprite getting distorted or its the whole canvas? its hard to figure out without a fiddle (could you make one) but at first glance it seems distortion is caused by the canvas on all children.

Comment: I thought makes the fan run faster thats why I was forcing canvas. Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: @EmmanuelNK I got the answer here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/40777-adding-child-to-sprite-distorts-childs-dimensions-location/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was posted by Ivon on [this forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/40777-adding-child-to-sprite-distorts-childs-dimensions-location/).

> Its a serious issue that exists for all the time of PixiJS, it even
>   predates pixi , it exists in Flash!
>
> The issue follows:
>
> 1. width and height props are evil. They are not first-class citizens. https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v4-Gotchas#width-and-height-are-evil
> 2. the behaviour cant be changed because of compatibility with flash. https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/dev/src/core/display/Container.js#L570
>
> Look here:
>   https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/dev/src/core/sprites/Sprite.js#L373
>   . Extend Sprite class, override getLocalBounds method that way it
>   ignores children, leave only the code inside that "if".

I solved my issue like this; instead of using PIXI.Sprite, I used PIXI.Container

```
export class ViewContainer extends PIXI.Container {
    bg: PIXI.Sprite

    constructor(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number, color: number, container: Container) {
        // as we're extending a class, we need to call the inherited classes constructor first
        super()
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.bg = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE)
        this.bg.tint = color
        this.bg.width = w
        this.bg.height = h
        this.addChild(this.bg)
        container.addChild(this)
    }

    addBorder() {
        let border = new PIXI.Graphics();
        border.lineStyle(.1,0xFFFFFF,1);
        border.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
        border.endFill();
        this.bg.addChild(border)
    }
}
```

Then I created the containers with this code

```
function createContainers() {
    let appW = app.renderer.view.width
    let appH = app.renderer.view.height

    cardContainer = new ViewContainer(0, appH*10/11, appW*2/5, appH/11, 0x3C2415, app.stage)
    actionContainer = new ViewContainer(appW*2/5, appH*10/11, appW*2/5, appH/11, 0x00FF00, app.stage)
    chatContainer = new ViewContainer(appW*4/5, 0, appW/5, appH/2, 0x008080, app.stage)
    playerContainer = new ViewContainer(appW*4/5, appH/2, appW/5, appH/2, 0xCCCCCC, app.stage)
    mapContainer = new ViewContainer(0, 0, appW - appW/5, appH*10/11, 0x0000FF, app.stage)
}
```

Now I'm able to position all the objects as I want with such code:

```
let settlement = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources.settlement_red.texture)
settlement.height = 10
settlement.width = 10
settlement.x = 0
settlement.y = 0
chatContainer.addChild(settlement)
```

[image: Result is here]